# Java web service tomcat not able to find a shared lib

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, jax-rs

I'm using eclipse and I have a java web service (rest jax-rs)
I also have another java project that contains a class Employee

In the web service project and I have gone to Java Build Path/Projects and added the project containing the Employee class.

No compilation erros.

In the web service I have a method like this:

```
    @GET
    @Path("{extra}")
    public Employee person(@PathParam("extra") String cus) {

        Employee p = new Employee();
        p.setName(cus);
        return p;

    }
```

When Run (it seems to starts tomcat server) I get the following error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: shared/Employee
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Class.getMethods(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.MethodList.getMethods(MethodList.java:77)
    com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.MethodList.<init>(MethodList.java:64)
    com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.MethodList.<init>(MethodList.java:60)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.modelapi.annotation.IntrospectionModeller.createResource(IntrospectionModeller.java:116)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.getAbstractResource(WebApplicationImpl.java:743)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.createAbstractResourceModelStructures(WebApplicationImpl.java:1518)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1295)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:167)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:773)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:769)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:769)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:764)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:488)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:318)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:399)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:317)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:204)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:182)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:311)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Obviously everything works when the Employee class is defined in the same project.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Java project needs to end up as JAR in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder of the deploy in order to be available in the webapp's runtime classpath. Only adding the Java project as project to the build path of the web project is not sufficient. This only covers the web project's compiletime classpath, not the webapp's runtime classpath.

You need to add the Java project in *Deployment Assembly* of the web project to get it to end up as JAR in `/WEB-INF/lib`.

[image: Eclipse Deployment Assembly screen]

Comment: How about if my shared library project has a dependency on Hibernate ... I also have to add hibernate jar into the deployment assembly? It can't detect automatically the dependencies?

Comment: You need to add them separately, yes. You can use the *Archives from Workspace* option in *Add* wizard for this.

Comment: What about configuration files like the hibernate.cfg.xml? I have it on my dataaccess project in a folder conf/hibernate.cfg.xml which was added as a class folder. Now my web werservice which has dependency on dataaccess project is complaning it cannot find the hibernate.cfg.xml ... should I create a hibernate.cfg.xml in the web service? Is that how it's suppose to work?

Comment: 2 options: 1) You should have created the `/conf` folder as a source folder instead. Rightclick project, *New > Source folder*. Or 2) You need to check the folder in *Export* tab of build path properties.